# Make disputed flags not be "disputed" if declined by a moderator

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-weight, disputed-flags

Currently, the behavior of flags in the 10k queue is this:

- If action is taken, either by the community or by a mod, the flag is "helpful" (positively affecting flag weight)
- If they are marked "invalid" by community members, they get forwarded to the ♦ queue. The mods can take action on them, but the flags get marked as "disputed" regardless of their validity. Disputed flags don't affect flag weight.
- If they aren't counterflagged/actioned by 10k users, and if a moderator sees them and declines them, then they have a negative effect on flag weight.

Wait... Back up there for a second... Does this mean that if *one user* (a mod) says the flag is bad, flag weight is reduced, but if *multiple users* (a mod and some 10kers) say the flag is bad, then the flag weight is not affected? That's right.

To me, this is completely illogical. A side effect of this will be that if a site has a good crowd of 10k users, then a user who keeps misflagging shall continue to do so (as the flag hellbanning will never be triggered.)

Jeff's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/how-should-we-handle-flag-weight-for-invalid-flags) about "pitting users against each other" is imo obsolete -- flag weight is no longer displayed and isn't that big a deal for most users (it is somewhat a big deal for mods, though).

I don't care much if [invalid flags give flag weight to the counterflaggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109790/disputed-flags-should-still-give-flag-weight-to-users-who-made-the-right-call) or not, but I feel that a flag correctly marked invalid should penalize the flagger at least as much as a normal declined flag. Either that, or some threshold of invalid flag votes should automatically mark a flag as declined.

---

I know that currently, all flags on a post (except spam/offensive) are treated as one big flag with the option to mark as helpful/declined, and you can't choose which flags to decline amongst these, but I'd like a change in this. Maybe make the invalid flag "special", similar to spam flags?

Comment: I agree, this is why more and more I don't even bother marking flags as invalid. What's the point? I may help a moderator, but I also help that user get off without any penalty.

Comment: The problem is that you can't decline the one flag and accept the others. All flags on one post are treated equal (except spam/offensive).

Comment: @animuson: Exactly. I can't give details, but I know for a fact that this has happened at least once (a user getting off without any penalty)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I know that. That's with the current system. I'm asking for a change in it :)

Comment: @Manish the last paragraph should have been in the post in one form or another from the start.

Comment: @DanielFischer: True, which is why I added it now..

Comment: @animuson: You know it!

Comment: This is crazy, so I flagged a post "not an answer", it says "disputed" although it's subsequently deleted. Very illogical it's not considered "helpful"...

Comment: @hayden: eh, I don't care much about flags not getting marked helpful.  That just makes it slower to get badges (if you're flagging correctly, flag weight shouldn't be a problem)

Answer (score 8):

I agree, and with the recent changes to flagging I think this needs to be revisited.

Every time I go through the SO flag queue, I see a few proper flags and a load of invalid ones.  There are clearly people who flag as "not an answer" anything with a question mark or that hints that the answerer ran into the question themselves, even when the post does provide a full and proper answer.  I really, really want to tell the mods that those flags are invalid, but I have stopped flagging as invalid because all that does currently is protect the original flagger from a net flag count (formerly flag weight) penalty.  The more deserving a flag is of being flagged invalid, the more it deserves a penalty, not to be protected from it.