# Disputing a flag should not affect the flag feedback

Tags: feature-request, flags, disputed-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disputed flags should still give flag weight to users who made the right call](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109790/disputed-flags-should-still-give-flag-weight-to-users-who-made-the-right-call)
>   [Make disputed flags not be “disputed” if declined by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161873/make-disputed-flags-not-be-disputed-if-declined-by-a-moderator)

10k users can dispute other users flags if they think the flag was in error. This has two major effect:

- The number of users that disputed a flag is visible to moderators
- The target flag is declared disputed, it doesn't affect [flag weight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flag-weight/info) either way, and the user will get the feedback that the flag was disputed in his flag history.

The first part is the useful part of disputing flags, as it provides the moderators some additional information, showing that a certain number of users disagree with that flag.

The second part is rather useless, and even actively misleading. The fact that the flag was disputed is not useful feedback, it only means that *any* user disagreed. Even if a dozen other users and a moderator agreed with the flag, it'll end up as disputed.

A user shouldn't even have to know that his flag was disputed, if the community or a moderator finally acted on it. The flag should be declared valid in this case.

Comment: What should happen to the disputed flag the 10k user cast? Should that  show "valid" or "declined" as well?

Comment: @Matt It shouldn't count for flag weight, as it does now, so neither valid nor declined. Ideally it would show wether the flag was validated by the community or a mod, or if it was declined.

Comment: That's what I'm driving towards... showing whether the flag you disputed was valid or not is the same as showing whether your `disputed` flag was helpful or invalid (declined). We almost might as well dispose of the "disputed" state *completely* and have *everything* as "valid" or "invalid" (declined).

Comment: My only concern with disputed flags is if a user who consistently flags improperly gets all of their flags disputed before we can decline them, then the user will never lose flag weight, and sometimes they can even be marked helpful allowing them to continue abusing flags until we must resort to suspension.

Comment: @Matt Yes, currently the feedback is exactly backward when you dispute a flag. The correct feedback for the disputing user would be the opposite of the feedback for the actual flag. Then there's the question on how to handle flag weight, I'd probably go with ignoring the dispute mechanism entirely for flag weight, disputing shouldn't affect the flag weight of the targeted user.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That is a pretty good argument for this feature, since I am assuming it would work both ways: the final state of the flag (valid/invalid) should count towards the user's flagging history, regardless of any intermediate disputed state. A user with a disputed flag that gets rejected should lose flag weight.

Comment: @Mad: Can enough disputed flags kick a vote out of the queue, or does it *always* have to be handled by a mod? If it's the latter, I think flag weight should *always* be affected; if 10kers are wrongly disputing flags, it's as much useless noise to mods as them wrongly flagging posts, no? (I'm not a mod!).

Comment: With regards to the duplicates, my feature request is not only about the flag weight but more about the feedback in the flag history.

Comment: @MadScientist I think the argument presented in the dupes was focused around on flag weight, but the overall effect would be that any disputed flag that is later approved/declined would be treated as if it was never disputed (this includes the feedback in the history and flag weight)