# What to do when a new user makes a post with a helpful link

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, review-audits, link-only-answers

Today I failed a test when reviewing late answers from new users. The user made a post with a single link and I didn't do anything with it.

The answer was useful, but it should have been a comment because it was only a hyperlink. Since new users can't write comments, it was the best thing he could do to help the questioner.

So I'd like to know what to do at posts like that one. Should I post the answer as a comment, and flag the question as "not an answer"? Or Should I just flag it and an operator will post it as a comment? Anyway I think, the user who posted the answer will lose something, because his help will appear with the name of somebody else.

Comment: Comment on the post that the user should summarise the content at the other end of the link. If they do, fine, if not, a later Not an Answer flag will be in order (you don't need to check back, sooner or later somebody else will happen across the answer).

Comment: @DanielFischer I would not flag as not an answer, I would suggest flagging with _other_ indicating it was a link only answer. Not an answer flags on links only have the tendency to be declined since they did in fact attempt to answer the question, even with a link.

Comment: @bluefeet [Whether link-only should be flagged as NaA or other is difficult to say.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1406527#1406527)

Comment: @DanielFischer Unfortunately, there is still [a lot of discussion about link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers) and no definitive answer on how to flag them

Answer (score 3):

As @daniel said in the comments, you should tell them that they should summarize the article while keeping the original source. If they fail to do this, report it as as Not A Answer, or change it yourself.

Comment: Once again; the consensus is _not_  to flag link-only answers as not-answers if they answer the questions.

Comment: @Jan, what consensus is that? I hope you're not referring to [this soup of conflicting opinions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta no. I am referring to [the highest voted (by a wide margin) answer  to that soup of opinions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183676/194047).

Comment: @Jan, I don't want to start a discussion as long as that one. But I find that whole answer, and everything it links to, as clear as mud, and full of conflicting guidance. Certainly not consensus.

Answer (score 0):

As the popup comes when anyone is about to write an answer, we can give there bold headlines if possible to make the answer more explanatory.

Even after that the user fails to provide sufficient information then we can edit that answer to add some description in it.