# Answer deleted without explanation - and without obvious flaw in the answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424485/572644) has just been deleted without explanation.

I would like to get one, because I don't see what the problem is.
ELMAH is a great library - with which I am *not* affiliated in any way - to log all kinds of exceptions in ASP.NET applications.
The question was tagged with ASP.NET, so the answer was not off-topic.
If the answer lacked substance, a simple comment would have been enough - I could have added more info.

Deleting an answer like this is just disrespectful and useless, because it gives me no possibility to learn.
I would post this as an answer anytime again, because *I don't know what is wrong with it*.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like an answer, just flag it for moderator attention to undelete it.

Comment: @Lucifer: I did already, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your flag, I undeleted your answer. Had you not brought this up to meta, it still would have gotten undeleted when the moderators went through the flag queue (which only has 242 flags right now!).

Your answer isn't amazing right now, but it's better than it was.

Your original answer:

> You can use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to easily log all exceptions.

It had a few issues:

- It recommended a solution without actually showing how it would solve the OP's problem. (If ELMAH is so easy to set up, why *not* include  example code or configuration on how to set it up?)
- It was one sentence long. Pretend the person who is asking the question is your spouse, and will make you sleep on the couch if you always just answer in a mere sentence.  You don't want to sleep on the couch, do you?

Take answers for what they are, *teachable moments*. You have the ability to teach hundreds of people who visit this post how to use ELMAH.  **Make it count**.

To address your comments:

> Deleting an answer like this is just disrespectful and useless, because it gives me no possibility to learn.

You're *mostly* right.  I wouldn't use the same inflammatory language, but deleting a post without a comment does not help you learn.  I wouldn't say it's useless, in that deletion does have its own feedback cycle, as this meta post proves.

We have hundreds of flags in the moderator queue every day (we receive 2500 daily).  If we were to respond with a comment to every single post we deleted, there'd be no time to actually remove bad posts.  Part of the reason moderators don't usually leave comments is that there's way to do so and still moderate the site.

In the past, [we've asked users to engage with other users instead of just summarily flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183676/16587).  People don't get flagging points for engaging, so they flag instead.  Incidentally, users *not* leaving comments leaves more work for moderators (which doesn't scale).

Of course, if you leave good answers, you're unlikely to ever have your answer deleted, rendering this discussion somewhat moot.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - and for undeleting mine.

Answer (score 9):

It is a link-only answer pointing to a package, with *no* explanation as to how that package would solve the OP problem.

You could have added a sample configuration at least.

Comment: Certainly, there is an explanation: It logs all exceptions. And even though, a comment would have been enough.

Comment: Alright, I added some substance and flagged for mod-attention. Let's hope he is as fast with undeleting as he is with deleting.......

Comment: See also the canonical Meta post on the issue @DanielHilgarth [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Fast enough? :-P

Comment: Indeed, thanks a ton! :)