# Possible illegal content linked on answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks

This [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606501/how-to-free-learning-complete-c-net-via-online) only answer suggested illegally downloading a book - I flagged it with other and this stipulation but it's been up for almost 24 hours. What else can I / should I do here?

Comment: Deleted now. Power to the mods! Oh wait, I'm not one.

Comment: Oh and I got my rep back for the downvote - *does a little dance*

Comment: Its deleted now buddy! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flagging the answer was fine, and the entire question should have been deleted, which it now has been.

Comment: Is there a better way to flag posts with illegal content to make sure they get done expediently? To explain, I've flagged posts for poor content or formatting that get worked on almost immediately - I would think that illegal content would be higher priority than those.

Comment: @jdphenix: In theory, yes, but the “Other” queue is obscenely long compared to the others at the moment (people also flood it with “link-only answer” and other things that should be covered by the existing presets…)

Comment: @minitech Given that the [official answer to “Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676) is “NO”, it's only to be expected that people would consider custom moderator flags as a reasonable choice. Sure, VLQ is now the right way to do it, but there is zero guidance that leads towards it.

Answer (score 0):

If the link can be removed without affecting answer validity, just use your edit super-powers. You usually don't kill a spider on the wall with shotgun.

If the answer is useless without link, it's link-only answer and should be flagged as being so.