# Enable the VLQ flag option on upvoted posts for users with good flagging history

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

On posts with a positive score, the very low quality flag option isn't enabled. This is great for many instances - if a post is +7, it's most likely high quality. We don't want unexperienced users flagging those.

However, this brings with it a problem when flagging link-only answers. Relatively often, a link-only answer will have a positive score - the link *is* useful. If the score is just +1, I downvote it, flag, and move on. If it's +2 or above, though, I'm kinda stuck.

I *could* use a custom flag, but 10kers don't get to see those - meaning the mod workload just got that much heavier. I could flag it as NAA, but it *is* an answer. It's just *very low quality*.

So, I propose that the VLQ flag option be reneenabled on positively-voted posts for users with *x* helpful flags - maybe 500? 1000? 50? The details can be worked out.

Opinions? Huge, gaping holes in my reasoning?

Comment: 1+ I agree with this. **[Here is an example of something I would flag as VLQ with over 21 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3315597)**, ironically, it's an awful audit I failed too..

Comment: how dare you. That would put Shog's favorite ["third example"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183709#comment586303_183709) into the danger of deletion. Get off your axe from his ["haXe"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1935355/839601 "full answer text: '[haXe][1] [1]: http://haxe.org/'")

Comment: -1: if a post is upvoted because people find it useful or like it, there is a reason for this. Wanting to flag by other people liked and appreciated posts (for political reasons, not because they contain mistakes or wrong things) for deletion is not nice (even downvoting is quite sourpussish) ... Why not just leave a comment and ask the OP, if he could give some (more) explanation?

Comment: On some subjective sites (Hermeneutics, I'm looking at you), it's not uncommon for people to upvote crap *that espouses opinions they agree with*, even if the answer is poor (like not supporting its claims, or is link-only, or is even NAA).  It would sure be nice for 10K users to be able to handle those wtihout sending custom flags to the mods (who often decline because they don't see a mandate to delete based on one flag).

Comment: For link-only answers, the solution is to edit in some context, and thereby make the post more valuable. Work, yes, but it really is the best option. However, @MonicaCellio points out other reasons why this might be valuable, so +1 from me.