# Highly upvoted and accepted link only answer

Tags: support, stack-overflow, link-only-answers

I ran into this question today:

[How to execute an SSIS package from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273751/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-net/273770#273770)

The accepted answer with 32 upvotes is just a link. Its a pretty old one too, which is probably why it hasn't been picked up by anyone. Is this flagable? I know in the good ol' days SO was a bit more lawless, but how should it be dealt with now?

Comment: `answered Nov 7 '08 at 21:53`

Comment: All posts have to comply to the same rules. The age of a post does not matter. Flag it.

Comment: I would not flag it, I would comment to the user (who is still around) asking if they could expand on their answer. If they don't, then suggest an edit to expand on it.

Comment: @bluefeet ...and you'd do that [24,000 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183709/165773 "to all link-only answers with positive score spread over at SO") right?

Comment: @gnat sure why not? if I run across them, I will post a comment to the user asking them to improve their answer.

Comment: @bluefeet more power to you. This way, it took us about 7 months ([March to October 2013](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6229/31260)) to cleanup link-only answers at Programmers, I guess it'll take about 700 months (about 60 years) to do so at Stack Overflow which is 100x times larger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead and converted that answer to a comment, as we would do today if flagged.

In particular since there is another, much more detailed and also highly voted answer.

Comment: very nice i like <= borat

Comment: Whoever downvoted - care to discuss?

Comment: Do you think that maybe a comment should have been left to the person who answered explaining why it was deleted, stating that if they expand on the link-only, then it could be undeleted?  I would be surprised if the person who received 32 upvotes doesn't post to meta asking why the answer was deleted.  If a comment was added before you deleted it, it might prevent any question.

Comment: @bluefeet - possibly. Though someone who has been on the site that long, with that kind of rep should understand without a comment.

Comment: I voted up cause the action was immediately taken

Comment: @Oded I'm just surprised by the fact that you deleted an accepted answer with 32 upvotes with absolutely no comment to the user.  I foresee a meta post asking why that happened.

Comment: @bluefeet - I did add a comment now... it is a fair point.

Comment: *I went ahead and converted that answer to a comment, as we would do today if flagged*. Not that I disagree with that, but is that the consensus?, according to this meta discussion it isn't (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers). I just want to understand what to do when faced with a link only answer that tried to answer the question

Comment: @Lamak - flag it. Doesn't matter how old it is. Doesn't matter how many upvotes it has. Doesn't matter if it is the accepted one. There is consensus that link only answers are low quality.

Comment: @Oded Ok, so I flag it as low quality, not "not an answer", right?

Comment: @Lamak - Right. "Not an Answer" is for things that are glaringly not answers (such as follow on questions, me too, thanks and such).

Comment: I don't think I agree with the conversion of this answer to a comment. Just because an answer consists of little more than a link doesn't necessarily mean we should remove it or convert it to a comment. The fact that this was accepted and highly voted showed that people found value in it. The link was not broken. I typically decline flags that ask us to remove older answers like this.

Comment: I support the move 100%. We close newer questions (sometimes of higher quality) and point them to older questions. Thus as the standards of the site evolve, the "older" Q&A's must evolve with them.