# Should we flag question titles that aren't very descriptive of the problem?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

Stack Overflow detects when your title is not good enough or not long enough.
I came across a lot of question like "Layout problem in Android". Does not give any clue until you read the question.
Should we flag them to avoid a lot of that in the community?

Comment: One option could be to edit the title

Comment: I see what you did there @Aaron

Comment: Do *not* flag stuff that should be edited -- just edit it and hope your edit is approved.

Comment: Sweet niblets, that edit is funny.

Comment: See, I can be funny sometimes.

Comment: Lesson learned! You @Aaron are a mean individual ...

Comment: I was going to add "Like this one?" to the end of the title, but thought that would be too mean. Demonstrated the point though, right?

Comment: It sure did! Answer goes to you. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Better yet: read the question, then edit the title, improving it accordingly. I do this all the time.

Not sure why you should flag it: is clarifying a title really the job of a moderator? Is improving content ever the job of a moderator? No, this is why we have edit privileges and why you can suggest edits when you haven't earned those - this is a community effort, not a moderator effort. Remember that moderators are not necessarily supposed to be subject matter experts across every single technology discussed on Stack Overflow, and they have enough to do anyway.

For ultimate irony, I just edited your question to improve its title. I didn't need to flag it and I am not a moderator here.

Comment: Snap! Pretty much what I was going to write.

Comment: Not like getting us to edit the title is going to change anything about the state of question titles anyway.

Comment: This is the answer.  As an aside, I wrote about good things to flag for moderator attention the other day. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190146/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That is an epic answer! Oh, and this is a good answer too, Aaron ;)