# What should each flag be used for?

Tags: support, flags

I know there are 5 different answer flags:

> - spam
>   Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.
> - rude or abusive
>   A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.
> - not an answer
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.
> - very low quality
>   This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.
> - in need of moderator intervention
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

When should I use each of these - example questions would be useful, including what not to flag. What should be done with link only answers and really badly formatted ones would be nice too.

Comment: What exactly do you think the [flag privilege and the links off of it doesn't cover](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?

Comment: @RobertLongson 2) It was 2 years ago so I don't remember that - having it as a meta post would not be a bad idea (that really isn't the place to look for how to guides). 2) Very few examples on those tbh.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), here are links to guides on when to use what flag:

- [Spam/Rude or Abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035):
- [Not an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392)
- [Off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824)
- [Very low quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606)
- [Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365)

And 'in need for moderator attention' is just when you think *something* needs to be done, but the action doesn't fit the above categories