# Are wrong answers non-answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, down-votes, not-an-answer

Suppose I ask, "What is the best way to add two numbers with my pocket calculator?" and someone answers "jQuery." That answer is obviously wrong, but it is technically an answer; they are suggesting something, it's just not the right something. Should I downvote and flag as a non-answer, or just downvote and possibly comment?

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295756/1017231

Comment: *That answer is obviously wrong* ... really? ... see [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think that answer is not useful then you should downvote it.

If you do not want to lose a point of reputation in order to help the site then you could just comment about the quality of the answer instead.

You should not flag it as Not An Answer because it looks like they have tried to answer but have made a not very useful attempt at doing so.